# Add parent object as attribute while mapping the child object with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, restkit

I have a very simple RestKit mapping for the following XML:

```
<category name="religious">
  <book isbn="42">HHGTTG</book>
  <book isbn="7">The bible</book>
</category>
```

Now when parsing this, I get a `category` object which contains two `book` objects. Now in my book object I want to have a reference to `category`.

This seems like a very easy thing to achieve but I did not find any of it in the [Object Mapping Documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping).

**Update**: This is what my mapping looks like:

```
RKObjectMapping *bookMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Book class]];
[bookMapping mapKeyPath:@"isbn" toAttribute:@"isbn"];

RKObjectMapping* categoryMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class]];
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
// Relationship to book
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"book" toRelationship:@"books" withMapping:bookMapping];
```

Comment: The HHGTTG, a religious book?  Blasphemy!  Also, category could be an NSDictionary if you wanted it to be.

Comment: @CodaFi What I want is that when the data is mapped, the `Book` object should be created with a reference to its parent object `Category`

Comment: @PauldeLange I updated my question with the mapping

Comment: @PauldeLange I would not say that this XML is un-RESTful, the `book` object have some sort of reference to the category by being enclosed in it...

Comment: If you read on the link you posted they use a belongsTo:WithMapping: method, but that seems to have disappeared. You will get much better answers as to why and what to do on the [RESTKit wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/)